# JQuery: dynamically retrieve value from autoNumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, autonumeric.js, val

I have a group of textbox on which I configured an autoNumeric (this plugin: https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric ):

```
$("input[name$='something']").autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ',', aSign: ' €', vMax: '99999999999.9999'});
```

When I post my form I want to reformat the values on the textbox:

```
function parseBeforeSubmit() {
    $("input[name$='something']").val(function(){
                                                    var myText = $(this)[0];
                                                    return myText.autoNumeric('get');
                                                });
}
```

obviously I cant get it working, what I'm seeing is that myText has a property called jQuery36000058939066319538821 which contains autoNumeric, but it seems strange that I can't dynamically access the autoNumeric component and also it seems this autoNumeric component doesn't contains the unformatted numeric value.

Sure there's something I'm missing or maybe I used the wrong approach?

Comment: Can you please post the plugin reference?

Comment: in the js i found: @version: 1.9.26 - 2014-10-07 GMT 2:00 PM, i'll add to the post

Comment: What is the expected format you want to set while calling parseBeforeSubmit? Are you trying to remove the separators and currency from the number?

Comment: Can you post a sample on jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Ok I digged a bit more, since I'm on a large project I just used autoNumeric on examples taken from others pages, but I have discovered that what I'm realling using is a specific implementation of autoNumeric: https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric
now I'm trying to understand if maybe this specific implementation provides some method to handle more autoNumeric in a single declaration.
I also prepared this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8u1kcsjo/

Comment: Yes, i wanted to remove separators and currency without losing decimals, I know It will be easier removing them as strings but seemed more "correct" to use autoNumeric to parse the values

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the call you are doing in your example are for `v1.9.*`, which is [deprecated](https://docs.autonumeric.org/Old%20documentation/v1.9%20documentation/).
If you can, you should use the latest version `4.6.0`, which is much more user friendly, and have [no jQuery dependency](https://docs.autonumeric.org/Developer%20guide/dependencies/).

If you want to modify the form input value before submitting, take a look at the specific [form functions](https://docs.autonumeric.org/Documentation/instantiated%20methods/#form-functions) in the official documentation.

Perhaps you'll need `formNumericString()`, `formArrayNumericString()` or `formJsonNumericString`, depending of your exact need.